# How to implement a custom typesafe collection using generic collections?

Tags: c#, collections, generic-collections, collectionbase, custom-collection

I used a strongly typed collection that derived from the `CollectionBase` class and now I'd like to change it to inherit from a typesafe generic collection. Some advise to inherit from `List<T>`, some do advise to use `Collection<T>`. What I'd like to do is this:

1) I have a custom class and I'm creating a collection that holds only the instances of that custom class.

2) I have some properties and methods that I'd like the custom collection class to have. For example, it should have an `Id` property, or it should have a `IsBlahBlah()` method.

How should I proceed with this? When I was deriving from the `CollectionBase` class, I was using the `InnerList` property to access the elements. Should I use the `Items` property if I choose to use `Collection<T>`?

Is doing something like:

```
public class MyCustomCollection : Collection<MyCustomClass>
{
    public int ExtraProperty { get; set; }

    public bool IsFortyTwo(MyCustomClass) { }
}
```

the right way? Will it work correctly out of the box without interfering with the methods in the `Collection<T>`?

Extra question: When I search for "Strongly Typed Collection" on Google, it always shows up results containing the `CollectionBase` class. What is the difference between *Strongly Typed Collections* and *Typesafe Collections*?

Answer (score 1):

**I think its need to implement like this**

```
public class MyCustomCollection
{
    private Collection<MyCustomClass> _collection = new Collection<MyCustomClass>();
    public int ExtraProperty { get; set; }
    public bool IsFortyTwo(MyCustomClass) { }
}
```

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is that when I add a `private Collection<MyCustomClass> _collection`, how does say `Collections.Add()` method know about my new collection and add the item to that? I think it has it's inner collection somehow.